# How to apply different formatting depending on whether number is positive or negative

Tags: c#, vb.net, double, string.format, formatting

I'm outputting a `Double` that can be either (+) or negative (-).  If the number is a negative the symbol (-) is included automatically, is there a way to do this for positive numbers as well?

The only (horrible) way I can do this is :

```
If MyNumber <= 0 then
    string.Format("{0:0.00}", MyNumber)
Else
    string.Format("+{0:0.00}", MyNumber)
End If
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the section separator in your format:

```
string.Format("{0:+0.00;-0.00}", num);
```

The format before the semi-colon will be used for positive numbers. The format after will be used for negative numbers. If you want a separate format for zero, add another format after the negative number format:

```
string.Format("{0:+0.00;-0.00;0.00}", num);
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this. +1  One comment, after looking this up on MSDN I think it's called a Section separator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("{0:+0.00;-0.00;0.00}”,MyNunber);
```